# Composite primary key in Access

Tags: ms-access, primary-key, ms-access-2003, composite-primary-key

I have a dataset for which the sole means of identifying each record is a customer name and a certificate number. For each purchase, the customer has a different certificate number (IE CustA has certificates 1-4, while CustB has certs 1-650) Neither field is unique, however together they uniquely identify a record. When I try to create a composite key, Access tells me that they would create duplicate values in the primary key. These keys are system generated so there cannot be a mistake with the naming/numbering.

Any way to fix this? My understanding is that this is how the system should work and that my dataset is errant, though I am assured that is not the case.

Comment: Did you create the key by dragging accross the two fields in design view and choosing primary key?

Comment: Access is telling you otherwise, it has just checked the data and found a duplicate.  Are there nulls?  Maybe this is something your 'system generated' doesn't consider.

Comment: @Fionnuala Yes, that's how I did it.

Comment: @cjb110 So it is - the IT developers who made the software that gave me the dataset were certain this wouldn't be a problem. With the scale of the dataset I hadn't manually checked, but there are about 10 duplicates. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is no Access issue, this a data issue. A PK cannot - by definition - have duplicates or Nulls.
Make a query to identify the culprits in your data:

```
select CustName, CertNum, count(*) as Counter
group by CustName, CertNum
having count(*) > 1
```

Otherwise your can create a surrogate PK using a Counter.
If it is a matter of Nulls, like cjb110 suggested, I can create a Unique Index with IGNORE NULLS. But until you fix nulls and duplicates, your 2 columns won't fit as a natural PK.

Comment: Right you are - there are duplicates. The guys who wrote this assured me this wouldn't be an issue, but I just checked and there are 10 duplicate entries. Many thanks

Comment: Never believe "them" ;-)